# I was able to make it so that the splash screen only plays when page loads first, but now it doesn't load after I close the page. Any way to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, splash-screen

I was able to make it so that my splash screen would only play once on page load, and would not play again, but after I close the tab, it does not play anymore, is there a way that I can fix it, or set a time limit where this JS function would reset? Can someone write the code in, it'd be very helpful :)

HTML:

```
<div class="splash">
    <h1 class="splash-content" id="content1">Sub/h1>
    <h1 class="splash-content" id="content2">Sub</h1>
    <h1 class="splash-content" id="content3">Sub</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.splash {
    background: black;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 4s;
}

.splash-content {
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(11em);
}

.splash.display-none{
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 1.5s;
}

.splash.post_animated {
    display: none;
}

#content1 {
    animation: come-in-first 2s ease-in;
}

#content2 {
    animation: come-in-second 3s ease-in;
}

#content3 {
    transform: translate(4px, 11em);
    animation: come-in-third 4s ease-in;
}

@keyframes come-in-first {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(13em);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes come-in-second {
    0%, 50% {
        transform: translateY(11.5em);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes come-in-third {
    0%, 60% {
        transform: translate(4px, 11.5em);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 6000);
})


var firstContainer = document.querySelector(".splash");

var result = localStorage.getItem('hasRan');

if (!result) {
        localStorage.setItem('hasRan', true);
} else {
    firstContainer.classList.remove("animated");
    firstContainer.classList.add("post_animated");
}
```

If you are confused, I am trying to make it so that the result function resets when the page is closed, that way the splash screen if you open the page again after closing the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you use the `sessionStorage` API instead of the `localStorage` API, so when the user closes the window, it resets.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 6000);
})


var firstContainer = document.querySelector(".splash");

var result = sessionStorage.getItem('hasRan');

if (!result) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('hasRan', true);
} else {
    firstContainer.classList.remove("animated");
    firstContainer.classList.add("post_animated");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first I will say you don't need other blocks of code except from this:

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 6000);
})
```

With this block of code you will achieve your desired result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

But if you insist to use the localStorage API. You will have to clear the localStorage first before anything else happens.

```js
localStorage.clear();

const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none');
  }, 6000);
})


var firstContainer = document.querySelector(".splash");

var result = localStorage.getItem('hasRan');

if (!result) {
        localStorage.setItem('hasRan', true);
} else {
    firstContainer.classList.remove("animated");
    firstContainer.classList.add("post_animated");
}
```

If you add that now everything will work perfectly